# Jquery loading animation until page finishes loading?

Tags: jquery, animation, loading

Can anyone show me how to play a loading animation until the webpage fully loads? I have no clue where to start so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check this : http://git.blivesta.com/animsition/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never build a loader before, but this is a start...
you can start by

hiding everything but loader with css,
using $(window).load to test, if the page is loaded such as.

```
$("#loader").animate(
        // your loader animation   
);

$(window).load(
    function() {
        // display content with .show() 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the quick response!
I actually ran across the page below giving a nice basic setup for it:

http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/